# Can I style different unordered list items separately?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using ReactJS and while creating my li elements (under a single unordered list), I've id'd half of them as questions and the other half as answers. When I print them, I want the answers more to the right and their bullets to be shown on the right of the text, just like two people are having a conversation. How can I achieve this?

```
renderPast = () => {
var return_value=[];
var flag = false;
for(var i = 0; i < this.props.question_number; i++){
  if(dummy){
    return_value.push(<li id="answers">{this.props.answers[i-1]}</li>)
  }
  return_value.push(<li id="questions">{this.props.questions[i]["text"]}</li>);
}
flag = true;
return return_value;
```

};

Comment: `li:nth-child(2n) { ... }` can be used to style the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc. `<li>`. Use `2n+1` instead to style odd ones. A more React based solution would be to use `.map((li, i) =>` in your render method and add a `className` based on whether `i % 2 === 0`.

Comment: @ChrisG I've realized that adding the code would make things easier so i'm editing the question

Comment: So add a class..... style the elements

Comment: ids are singular. FYI

Comment: @epascarello couldn't do it, the tutorials i followed on the internet don't seem to work, or i couldn't handle it :( I'm new to the web concepts so...

Comment: @ChrisG why not use `nth-child(even)` or `odd` instead of using an `n` value?

Comment: You can not do `class="answer"` and `class="question"` and write a CSS rule? `.answer { padding-left: 2em; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, but you may want to utilize react's templating a little more heavily.  It makes things much easier to read and manage.  Also, you should only use a unique ID on one single element.  Multiple elements with the same ID interferes with accessibility and scripts that may depend on fetching a single element.  Additionally, semantically speaking, your list is better off if each item is consolidated into question-answer pairs.

```html
  <li class="item" rt-repeat="question in this.props.questions">
    <span class="question">
      {question["text"]}
    </span>
    <span class="answer" rt-if="this.dummy">
      {this.props.answers[questionIndex-1]}
    </span>
  </li>
```

Your css can then be used to style these classes in order to make them appear on the right or the left side.  For example, the way I was able to accomplish this is by using relative positioning and assigned widths.
Remember, `75%` + `25%` = `100%` only works if `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`.

```css
.allItems {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.question,
.answer {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 75%;
}

.question {
  background-color: #e1f5f5;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  color: #245366;
  left: 0;
}

.answer {
  background-color: #e2f5e1;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  color: #384738;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="allItems">
  <li class="item">
    <span class="question">Can I ask a demo question?</span>
    <span class="answer">I'll give you a demo answer.</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="question">Can I ask a demo question?</span>
    <span class="answer">I'll give you a demo answer.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the `id` attributes to `className` instead. id's are only meant to be used on one element and this will render every question or answer with the same id.

Then in your css file you can style them with:

```
.questions{
  // Question styles here
}

.answers {
 // Answer styles here
}
```

Then import your css file.